# Guidelines for home generation of hypochlorous acid disinfectant from salt water

Tags: acid-base, safety, electrolysis

I bought a home generator for making hypochlorous acid by electrolysis of a water and salt solution.  I would like to figure out guidelines for safe and effective use of my generator.

I have found multiple resources saying that hypochlorous acid solution is not harmful to people or animals and yet very effective as a disinfectant.  A lab made mice drink it instead of water for weeks with no observed ill effects; the FDA allows it to be used as a no-rinse disinfectant in food prep areas; and people routinely put it into "foggers" to disinfect areas where people might go.  I just want something to put into a spray bottle and disinfect the toilet or whatever, so this seems like one of the safest possible disinfectants; and now that I have a home generator I can make it by the litre anytime I need more.

It breaks down quickly, but I believe it will still be effective for up to a week, and it's just a few pennies worth of ingredients and electricity to make another batch.

The device came with a terse instruction booklet, which is written in reasonable English but nonetheless leaves me with questions.

The booklet says to mix 2 litres of water with 12 grams of pure salt (I'm planning to use kosher salt).  Then activate the electrolysis and let it run.  Then dilute the solution 4:1 before using.  Here is a table of suggested times for electrolysis:

- 5 minutes to make 200 PPM
- 15 minutes to make 500 PPM
- 30 minutes to make 1000 PPM

The device has a built-in timer that can be set for these three time intervals, and then stops the electrolysis automatically.

When I bought the device, the Internet retailer web site showed me that often people buy test strips with it.  I thought that was a good idea so I bought both pH test strips and chlorine PPM test strips.

The booklet does not discuss this, but I have read that it is a good idea to add vinegar to the water as well as salt, because there are multiple possible reactions when you electrolyze the saline solution, and you want the hypochlorous acid solution and not sodium hypochlorite.  And in fact there is one brand of home hypochlorous acid generator that sells small plastic capsules containing a pre-measured mixture of vinegar and salt.  (Their web site claims the FDA requires them to sell the pre-measured capsules to make sure the end user gets the recipe correct.)

I searched the Internet for a set of guidelines for the home user, and found a discussion on another site that urged adding a *base* rather than an acid to the salt solution before electrolysis.  I've only seen that one place; the suggestion to add vinegar seems to be the common advice.

The booklet says the reaction is:

NaCl + H20 -> NaClO + H2^

I've seen videos of devices like this in operation and bubbles appear in the water; presumably that's the H2.  Is there any worry it might generate chlorine gas or anything else bad?  I'm planning to use this in a well-ventilated area.

We have a large supply of powdered citric acid, so I would like to work out a recipe that uses citric acid and salt instead of vinegar and salt.  According to a video I found, ideally the salt solution should have a pH of "between 4 and 5".  So presumably I can just start mixing citric acid powder with my tap water, and using my pH test strips, until I find the correct amount of citric acid powder to get a 4.5 pH solution.  But I thought I should ask here first before I try it.

And I would like to know what I should expect to see on the test strips if the reaction was the desired one.  What should I expect the final pH to be?  Presumably the PPM test just shows PPM directly and should match what I'm trying to make by setting the timer.

I'd like a recipe to make 1 litre at a time.  And ideally I'd like to work out a recipe I can use without diluting it... one litre of spray disinfectant easily should last me a week; I don't need to make 4 litres at a time.

References:

The generator I bought:

- https://www.gosoitwater.com/all-purpose-cleaner-maker-machine-disinfectant-sanitizer-cleaner-p2580977.html
- [https://amazon.com/GOSOIT-Multi-Purpose-Detergent-Deodorant-Personal/dp/B085TFB5Z2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B085TFB5Z2)

Article suggesting that hypochlorous acid is a safe and effective disinfectant:

- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7315945/

EPA listing of disinfectants known to be effective against SARS-CoV-2, which includes hypochlorous acid:

- https://www.epa.gov/pesticide-registration/list-n-disinfectants-coronavirus-covid-19

FDA allows it for food prep with no rinse:

- https://www.hypochlorousacid.com/regulation

The generator that sells pre-measured capsules of vinegar and salt:

- https://www.forceofnatureclean.com/natural-cleaner-and-disinfectant/

Discussion on another site suggesting that one should add a base, not an acid, to the water:

- https://communities.acs.org/thread/10731-need-help-understanding-the-production-of-hypochlorous-acid-and-byproducts

One of the many videos I found about making hypochlorous acid:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=te8C0bo_Zrc

A video showing a recipe to use instead of the pre-mixed plastic capsules:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5sNlwO6_gco

Comment: In short, hypochlorite ion is nothing but chlorine bleach used un laundry. You should not follow any scam or disinfectant generators for home. These are not safe products. Do not add vinegar with salt during electrolysis. Most likely you might form cancer causing substances. Alternatively, citric acid or vinegar and salt are good for nothing as disinfectants.

Comment: The only reasonable use for hypochlorite at home is in a pool. Don't go disinfecting stuff unless your doctor urges you to, usually because you have a norovirus or similar at home.

Comment: @M.Farooq I gave you references explaining why I thought this is a good idea.  You haven't given me anything other than what appear to be your personal opinions.  Please provide references if you wish to persuade me.  "These are not safe products"  Okay, here's the Safety Data Sheet for Force of Nature.  Please tell me what you consider most unsafe part: https://www.forceofnatureclean.com/force-nature-material-safety-data-sheet-2/  If you think Force of Nature is safe and the gadget I bought isn't... why?

Comment: @steveha, If someone tells you that playing and splashing hot boiling water may cause injury or burn your skin, will you call it a "personal opinion" and ask for references? Sorry it is not anyone's job to persuade you not using a commercial dubious gadget. All that was said was that hypochlorite disinfectant is nothing but a laundry bleach. You do not need to prepare bleach at home, which is prepared commercially with full safety. And your idea of adding vinegar and salt in the electrolysis cell can potentially generate carcinogens. Do you see close votes by SE readers?

Comment: Head over to https://www.sciencemadness.org/whisper/ and post this in the Technochemistry forum! There are a lot of people interested in this.

Comment: I hope the well-sourced answer provided below is of assistance.  The closing of this question (on which I have voted to reopen) and my unwarranted down vote, is more of a forum policy issue to avoid giving advice on health issues (aka, fear of liability issues) and should not be construed of any lack of accuracy per my many government-based sources or the significance or quality of the presentation of your question. I do agree with the opinion, however, that adding vinegar is a potentially bad idea, and explaining why is also equally important.

Comment: @M.Farooq Various branches of the US government recommend hypochlorous acid solution as a safe and effective disinfectant.  I provided you with a Safety Data Sheet for a commercial gadget similar to the one I bought, and if you actually read it you will see that it contains statements like "c. Carcinogenic Effects: Negative  d. Mutagenic Effects: Negative"  In return you provided unsourced opinions such as that it "can potentially generate carcinogens."  Don't worry, I see that this question was unwelcome in this community; and indeed I feel unwelcome here personally, so I'll be gone soon.

Comment: @John I visited the site you suggested, and tried to register as a user.  I got an error message that the function I attempted to use is disabled at this time.  I looked to see if I could post a new topic without being a user, and didn't see any way to do it.  So, I posted my question on Quora.  Maybe next week I'll try the site you suggested again.  If you are able to post there, I'd welcome you posting this question there; I don't care if I can join the site, I just want an answer.

Comment: Here's my last word on the question.  If you want to make HOCl solution for use as a cleaner and disinfectant, I recommend you buy the "Force of Nature" (FoN) product.  FoN is an "electrolyzer" which you fill with water to a line and then you add a pre-measured pouch (which actually contains only a small amount of vinegar and salt).  Plug it in, push the button, bubbles fizz and in five minutes you have 16 ounces of HOCl solution.  It's safe enough to spray in your eyes yet the US government lists it as an effective sanitizer.  I have no connection with FoN.

Comment: I bought a total of three gadgets.  The first one was a total mistake.  The second one was an Ecolox Eco One, which works okay but we found less convenient than the third one, "Force of Nature" (FoN).  FoN sells little plastic pouches with pre-measured portions of salt and vinegar; the Eco One just has a recipe and a measuring spoon.  It would be possible to make your own FoN mix if you wished and people do that, but I wouldn't dream of suggesting something like that here because someone would accuse me of creating mutagens or something.

Comment: As for the actual answer to my question: I found a description of the reaction these perform.  Visit this page to see a graph: https://hocl.com/hocl-chemistry  By reading the graph you can plainly see that if the pH of the solution is between 4 and 5 the reaction will make HOCl and essentially no free chlorine.  If you allow the pH to get too low, free chlorine would be produced.  I bought test strips and made sure that the recipes I personally made had the proper pH to avoid producing free Cl2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my comments having extensively studied (pending patents) and produced (albeit not via electrolysis) hypochlorous acid ($\ce{HOCl}$) for various applications.

First, a possible issue I have is the mentioned use of vinegar, an organic acid, to the mix. The reason arises if not employing distilled water (meaning you may be using tap water rich in transition metal ions). The latter can react with $\ce{HOCl}$ in a Fenton-type reaction (detailed below) introducing radicals. Depending on whether the pH is greater or less than 5, you obtain either the more powerful hydroxyl radical ($\ce{.OH}$) or the chlorine radical ($\ce{.Cl}$), so a pH of 5 to 7 is preferable. The introduction of the chlorine radical allows the potential attack of organic compounds providing a path to chloro-organics, a potential health issue if consumed internally (externally, for surface disinfecting, a lesser concern with proper ventilation). Note, the action of the $\ce{.OH}$ radical on aqueous chloride ($\ce{Cl-}$ from salt) can also be a source of the chlorine radical (see chemistry detailed below).

Note, the action of even a weak acid on Sodium hypochlorite ($\ce{NaOCl}$), like dilute acetic acid found in vinegar, will form $\ce{HOCl}$ (including also very [dilute mineral acids](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4160982/) at pH 6). Hypochlorous acid is cited to be nearly 100 times more powerful in disinfecting than $\ce{NaOCl}$ (see [related comments here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4160982/) and [elsewhere](http://www.aerosia.com/popup_article.php?link=article_6.htm)). As such, one could be faced with a decision in the presence of transition metal ions to balance the immediate dangers of drinking a water source which may lead to a rapid onset of a fatal disease with choice of either weaker $\ce{NaOCl}$ or more powerful $\ce{HOCl}$. Interestingly, one can apply carbon dioxide, as an acid gas, to $\ce{NaOCl}$ as a path to hypochlorous acid, and avoid the chloro-organics issue. The associated radical formed than becomes the less powerful (but much-prolonged life span) carbonate radical anion ($\ce{.CO3-}$ formation detailed below) in place of the more reactive, but transient, hydroxyl radical.

Also, iron and copper are transition metals, so avoid using as electrodes in an electrolysis path to hypochlorite/hypochlorous acid if you want a product with a longer shelf-life. Hypochlorous is itself, with exposure to sunlight or even air rich in dust particles, or $\ce{HOCl}$ in contact with an anodic metal source (like stainless steel creating a battery cell) should not be expected to have a long shelf life (more like hours).

Some details on the cited chemistry with sources, in the presence of iron or copper ions:

First, from "Fenton chemistry in biology and medicine" by Josef Prousek, to quote reaction (15) on page 2330, a general depiction of Fenton-type reactions, to quote:

"For Fe(II) and Cu(I), this situation can be generally depicted as follows [20,39],

Fe2+/Cu+ + HOX → Fe3+/Cu2+ + ·OH + X- (15)

where X = Cl, ONO, and SCN. "

In a possible presence of copper ions:

$\ce{Cu -> Cu+ + e-}$

$\ce{Cu+ -> Cu++ + e-}$

$\ce{HOCl + e- <-> •ClOH-}$   (see, page 13, [Table 1.2a here](https://www.bnl.gov/isd/documents/92710.pdf) and Supplement Table S1, link below, Reaction [1] )

$\ce{•ClOH- <-> Cl- + •OH}$  (pH > 5, see Eq(8), page 8, same source as above)

Also, different radicals and products at low pH:

$\ce{•ClOH- + H+ -> H2O + •Cl}$   (pH < 5, k = 2.1×10^10 Source: Eq (7) in Supplement Table S1 [available here](http://www.mdpi.com/1420-3049/22/10/1684) and click on provided Supplement File 1 to download)

And, with a bicarbonate or chloride presence (likely in the electrolysis of NaCl):

$\ce{HCO3- + .OH -> H2O + .CO3-}$  (see [Carbonate Radical in Natural Waters](https://www.collectionscanada.gc.ca/obj/s4/f2/dsk1/tape4/PQDD_0028/NQ50045.pdf))

$\ce{Cl- + •OH -> •Cl + OH-}$

$\ce{Cl- + •Cl -> •Cl2-}$  (Eq(12) in [Supplement S1](https://www.mdpi.com/1420-3049/22/10/1684) file link)

where radicals, especially $\ce{•OH}$ can attack and breakdown organic compounds.

Comment: Where is Eq($8$) above ? There is nowhere an Eq($8$).  And also, please, don't oblige us to read the $294$ pages of the" table available here"

Comment: Maurice: Yes, a little confusing. I did an edit to more clearly note that it is a reference to the Supplement Table S1 (look for Supplement File material section and click link). Note, Equation  (12) in the cited work. – AJKOER 4 mins ago

Comment: Thank you for providing a thorough answer.  Since my question was closed yours might be the only answer I will get here.  I don't have a sufficient understanding of chemistry to fully engage with your answer but I'll try to comment usefully.

Comment: First, in re: to the vinegar: it's not my idea but seems to be common in this area, and is standard in the Force of Nature capsules.  Force of Nature got an EPA certification and they recommend tap water.  However, the one I bought (the Gosoit device) does not recommend vinegar.  The second YouTube video I linked has a person recommending the use of vinegar to make sure the reaction primarily produces hyopchlorous acid, along with a chart of unknown source showing that a slightly acid pH is ideal.  My tap water is neutral or very slightly basic.

Comment: Second, the Gosoit product page, which I linked, includes this claim: "...with latest Platinum coated Titanium (SPE) electrolysis Plates and the long lifetime Proton Membrane (PEM) made by DuPont in the USA."  I was interested to read your concern about the use of iron in an electrode; on this point I think you can be reassured.  That page further says: "Only electrolysis water and salt into sodium hypochlorite disinfectant"  So your anti-recommendation for vinegar matches with the official product advice.

Comment: Third, as for shelf life, I have seen a wide variety of claims for shelf life.  There are numerous bottled products that claim to be stabilized hypochlorous acid; some people claim the homemade stuff is good for two weeks; some claim one week; and Gosoit recommends using the solution within 6 hours!  On balance I was assuming that I could probably keep a bottle of solution for a week.  I expect to usually use the solution right after making it.

Comment: Okay, I have read through your answer a few more times and I think I am understanding it a little better.  It sounds like ideally I should use distilled water rather than tap water, but it also sounds like you aren't super-concerned about it.  pH between 5 and 7 is recommended, which matches other advice I have seen.  On my first reading I thought you were recommending against the vinegar but now I think you aren't.  In any event I was planning to use citric acid powder.  I've upvoted and accepted your answer.  Thank you.